# How to get the key name dynamically from the list in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

How to get the key name dynamically from the list and push it to an array using NodeJS.

This is my string `{ PRICE: '12', TYPE: 'Electronics' }`

I want to push the key name `PRICE`, `TYPE` to an `array` like below:

```
const myArray = ["PRICE", "MyOrg::PRICE", "TYPE", "MyOrg::TYPE"]
```

I don't know how to get the key name dynamically from the list and push it to an array - can someone pls help me with this. Thanks.

**Sample code:**

```
const test = async () => {

        const myList =  { TYPE: '12', REGION: 'Electronics' }

        // Execpted array like below
        const myArray = ["PRICE", "MyOrg::PRICE", "TYPE", "MyOrg::TYPE"]


  };
  
  test();
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: Thank you ariel, I want to read the key one by one and append the key with my custom string like this MyOrg::<KeyName> as part of my array. How can I do that?

Comment: Is the order of the elements relevant? Does `PRICE` need to be before `MyOrg::PRICE` & `TYPE` before `MyOrg::TYPE`? If not: `const newArr = [Object.keys(myList), ...myArray]`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do `Array.concat` with `Object.keys`

```js
const myList = { TYPE: '12', REGION: 'Electronics' };
let myArray = ['PRICE', 'MyOrg::PRICE'];

myArray = myArray.concat(Object.keys(myList));
console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Question doesn't really make sense. The following code generates the output that you are asking for, but it doesn't seem useful.

```js
const myList = { "PRICE": 12, "TYPE": "Electronic" };

const myArray = [];

Object.keys(myList).forEach( function (key) {
    // Loop through all the keys
    myArray.push(key)
    myArray.push("MyOrg::"+key)
})

console.log(myArray)
// Expected output
// myArray == ["PRICE", "MyOrg::PRICE", "TYPE", "MyOrg::TYPE"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need [variable substitution](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_templates.asp) in your code, that you get by enclosing variable  with curly braces like this `${variable}`.

```js
const myList =  { TYPE: '12', REGION: 'Electronics' }
array = Object.keys(myList)
myArray = []
for (let element of array){
    myArray.push(element, `MyOrg::${element}`)
}
console.log(myArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce` with `concat`

```js
const myList =  { TYPE: '12', REGION: 'Electronics' }
 
const  results = Object.keys(myList).reduce(
                        (a, b) => a.concat([b, "My0rg::" + b]), []);

console.log(results)
```